# Airflow DAG processing for new clients

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm new to Airflow and I understand how DAGs' `start_date` + `time_interval` work for my own company for example pulling Google Ads historical data.

But we're doing analysis for multiple clients data.

How do I structure DAGs to handle new client's data? I don't want to create a new DAG for every client onboarded, even if programmatically, that seems poor.

Also since new clients can come in any time, I'd like to pull data when clients create accounts which is event driven. I could use the experimental Event Driven API but is there a better approach?

Is Airflow not a good solution for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain the clients data in a persistent storage(database) and schedule your dag to reference this data and call api's accordingly.

If you need this as real time as possible and make it event driven I can think of aws solutions like lambda,s3 which are more appropriate for event driven architecture.

Let me know if this answers your question.